# Error while trying to test a JS Class using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I got a react app in which I have created a utility class called `Logger` (not a React component). I now want to create some tests for the class using Jest.

Jest is installed, and I created a file called `Logger.test.js` in the same folder as the class. When running `npm test` I get this error:

> Cannot find module '../Logger' from 'Logger.test.js'

I got no file called jest.config.js anywhere, and there is nothing in the package.json file which is reserved for configuring jest (jest is only mentioned there in the dependencies).

How can I make Jest realize that the class is a module it needs to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to import from the parent folder in the error message: `../Logger` . Should be `'./Logger'`

Comment: Yes, I imported the class so I can use it in a test. How should I have done it?

Comment: I think he means to say that you imported it from wrong directory.